# Can I filter laravel collection using where method and some other Model's method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model called Billboard. In this model I wrote a method `isDisplayable()`.

```
   public function isDisplayable()
   {
      if  (/* Logic to determine if billboard is displayable */)
        return true;
     return false;
   }
```

I want the collection of Billboards that are only displayable. Can I utilize **Where** method with isDisplayable()? or should I adopt some other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the Collection, you can use the `filter()` method to filter out results based on your Model method:

```
$billboards = Billboard::all();
$filtered = $billboards->filter(function ($billboard, $key) {
    // true to keep; false to remove
    return $billboard->isDisplayable();
});
```

If you want to use this logic on a query (before the Collection is even built), you can create a query scope on your `Billboard` model:

```
public function scopeDisplayable($query, $displayable = true)
{
    if ($displayable) {
        // modify $query to only get displayable items, e.g:
        $query->where('displayable', '=', 1);
    } else {
        // modify $query to only get non-displayable items, e.g:
        $query->where('displayable', '=', 0);
    }
}

// use your new query scope like any other method on the query builder:

// displayable billboards:
$billboards = Billboard::displayable()->get();

// non-displayable billboards:
$billboards = Billboard::displayable(false)->get();
```

Comment: From the `filter()` function I get the following error: `Missing argument 2 for {closure}()`. What is wrong? Well, I have just solved by deleting the `$key` variable. Thanks.